# Error when open uiautomatorviewer in android SDK tool

Tags: android, android-testing

I tried to run uiautomatorviewer tool in android sdk by these command in terminal

> cd adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools/
>
> ./uiautomatorviewer

And I get error below

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Can anyone explain it for me and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try updating android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
and increase -Xms128m to -Xms512m and restart Android Studio.